# Audio doesn't play in setInterval function when time is too short

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm new to Javascript/Jquery programming, and I'm trying to code a simple program where every certain milliseconds a short audio file is played, the problem is that when I input a short time, the audio playback skips once every other time.

Is it possible to solve this in a simple way?

Here's how I'm calling playback from an HTML audio element:

```
document.getElementById('tick').play();
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried at Question?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add a "stop" function before next playback, now it works fine.

```
function stopSound(){
        document.getElementById('tick').pause();
        document.getElementById('tick').currentTime=0.0;}
```